# Custom IPrincipal with application name IsInRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider

I'm implementing a custom `IPrincipal` that I want to use across multiple applications.
I have 2 questions about the `IsInRole` method...

1) Is it recommended that I use a custom RoleProvider with the custom `IPrincipal`? I could always put the logic that checks the users roles in the class that inherits from IPrincipal.

Something like:

```
public class SSDSPrincipal : IPrincipal
{ 
    public SSDSPrincipal(SSDSIdentity identity)
    {
        this.Identity = identity;
    }        

    public IIdentity Identity {get;private set;}

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {   
        string[] roles = Roles.Providers["SSDSRoleProvider"].GetRolesForUser(Identity.Name);
        return roles.Any(s => role.Contains(s)); 
    }
}
```

2) Because I want to use this across multiple MVC3 applications. Where is the best place to store the application name? I need to be able to set this manually.

```
public bool IsInRole(string role)
{   
    string applicationName = [where can I store this globally for my asp.net mvc3 app]
    return AreTheyInARoleForThisApplication(applicationName, role);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you are free to use whatever technique you want in order to find out if a use is in a role. A RoleProvider isn't a must here.

Can't you pass on the application name as a constructor parameter then store it in a member?

Comment: I think I'll avoid using the custom role provider then. Checking if a user is in a role is the only functionality I really need. Passing in the application name sounds good...Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't have to have a role provider, however if you do, the idea is that your custom role provider should inherit from System.Web.Security.RoleProvider so that it can be interchanged for any other role provider without breaking the application

2) web.config or app.config are the proper place for this